# Problem with colors when making a CMYK document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk, rgb, color-spaces, color-management

I'm making my portfolio and as I understand, everything that has to be printed has to be set in the CMYK color mode. So, I chose CMYK. I'm using Illustrator CC 2018. The file tab shows the information `My portfolio (CMYK/Preview/U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2)`.

Now, after a while, when I look back at everything, all the bitmaps I placed (like logos or graphics that were saved as PNGs on my computer), their blacks look gray. Moreover, every color looks less vivid in a way and duller. It's almost like a layer of faded black or gray is overlayed over everything.

I know this is a common phenomenon -- whatever you make in RGB initially and then convert to CMYK will look duller, but **is there a way to get around it?** I don't want my purples to look faded, dull purples.

And as for blacks in the shapes I'm creating, I don't want rich black to be printed but CMY=0 K=100 was too ... gray, so I went for C=75 M=68 Y=67 K=90 which is a more ["true black"](https://www.bittbox.com/culture/photoshop-101-true-black-cmyk). It's better and I guess it's **the closest you can get to RGB black in CMYK?**

Comment: What kind of printing are you doing?  Digital printing, lithography, screen printing, or something else?  When you say "everything that has to be printed has to be set in the CMYK color mode" that's not exactly true.  CMYK is only a requirement for print processes which involve the use of separations for printing.

Comment: As in printing a booklet on photo paper.

Comment: What kind of printing? Inkjet? CMYK is not required for inkjet printing, in fact most consumer grade inkjets can't even print CMYK images properly.